# Existing function "is not a function"

Tags: javascript

Check the console with this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1207bhjd/) which says the following in Chrome:

> Uncaught TypeError: handlerHelper(...) is not a function

```
"use strict"

function parseRoute(route, Handlers){
  let parsed = Handlers
  route.split('->').forEach(function(s){
    parsed.hasOwnProperty(s) && (parsed = parsed[s])
  })
  return parsed
}

function handlerHelper(Handlers, ev){
  let parsed = parseRoute(ev.name, Handlers)
  applyHandlers(parsed, ev)
}

function applyHandlers(obj, ev){
  for (let i in obj) { 
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(i)){
      console.log(handlerHelper, typeof handlerHelper)
      typeof obj[i] === 'object'
        && handlerHelper(obj[i], ev)

      (i = obj.handlers)
        && i.length
        && i.forEach(function(fn){
        fn.apply(null, ev)
      })
    }
  }
}

handlerHelper({
  $: {
    handlers: [function(){}]
  }
}, {
  name: '$->Test'
})
```

On the console it clearly says it is function.
This is a recursive function and it throws only after in the 3rd iteration.
Really weird. Any clues about what's the problem?

Comment: What line is erroring out?

Comment: If you're going to elide semicolons like some of us do, you should consider adopting a set of practices where you never start a line with a binary or unary postfix operator without including a leading `;`. Also, I'd personally avoid using the return value of an assignment as a logical condition like you're doing, as well as logical operators for flow control. Let your minifier handle that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lack of semicolons is the issue:

```
    && handlerHelper(obj[i], ev)

  (i = obj.handlers)
```

This is the same as:

```
    && handlerHelper(obj[i], ev)(i = obj.handlers)
```

And `handlerHelper` does not return a function, thus the error. You need a semicolon there:

```
    && handlerHelper(obj[i], ev)

  ;(i = obj.handlers)
```

Comment: Indeed, I'd rewrite that properly.

Comment: @wintercounter: eslint can help you catch those ASI errors.

Comment: I have but didn't throw any warning in PhpStorm.